# How can I get the HTML for an element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the exact HTML of the element I want

like if I have this:

```html
<div class="input">
  <input type="number" id="nanometer" autocomplete="off" class="field" placeholder="nm" oninput="exchange()">
</div>
```

I want to get that exact HTML code in my JavaScript:

```
var nano = document.getElementById("nano")
```

and now I expect `nano` to be:

```
<input type="number" id="nano" autocomplete="off" class="field" placeholder="nm" oninput="exchange()">
```

and for my work, I have to make it duplicate itself like this:

```
<input type="number" id="nano" autocomplete="off" class="field" placeholder="nm" oninput="exchange()">
<input type="number" id="nano" autocomplete="off" class="field" placeholder="nm" oninput="exchange()">
```

by this code:

```
document.getElementById(nano).outerHTML += nano
```

but it wont work

Comment: `var html = document.getElementById("nano").outerHTML` ? isn't it?  But remember, `id` **must** be unique, if you duplicate the element with same id, you'll have invalid HTML

Comment: this `var html = document.getElementById(nano).outerHTML` gets the whole html codes in the <div> bu i want it to get just it self, and i doesnt matter if the id gets copied, because if i make the javascript code o it, i have plans to change the ids in another copies

Comment: which div? Please, share with us your current relevant code, take a look at [mcve]

Comment: @Rawand id values must be **unique** through the entire document; you cannot re-use ids.

Comment: You might ask about what you're actually trying to do rather than this specific operation. See [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/247976).

Comment: something like this: [link](https://codepen.io/RawandHr/pen/dyPxLmm)

Comment: So you want to clone an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the question is for making a clone using HTML strings, it is better to not work with HTML strings but with **DOM elements** instead. Those are the objects that a browser uses internally.

Using DOM elements it is **much** easier to control the results, esp. if you need to make changes to the new item - such as giving it a new **`id`**, which is mandatory because every **`id`** on every page should be unique.

Here is an example:

```js
var nano = document.getElementById("nano");
var parent = nano.parentNode;

var clone = nano.cloneNode(true);
clone.id = "newNano";
clone.setAttribute("value", 123);

parent.insertBefore(clone, nano.nextSibling);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="nano" autocomplete="off" class="field" placeholder="nm" oninput="exchange()">
```

Answer (score 0):

First, get the outer HTML. Then, to duplicate it, you have to append the new HTML to the *parent* node of whatever you're trying to get. Also, you would need to replace the new ID with something unique. So it would be:

```js
    var nano = document.getElementById("nano"),
        outer = nano.outerHTML,
        newOuter = outer.replace(
          'id="',
          'id="' + Date.now()
        ),
        parent = nano.parentNode;
    
    parent.innerHTML += newOuter;
    console.log(parent.innerHTML)
```

```html
<div>
<input type="number" id="nano" autocomplete="off" class="field" placeholder="nm" oninput="exchange()">
</div>
```

Comment: @CalvinNunes OK so just add anotehr line newouterHTML  = outer.replace("id=", "id='" + Date.now() + "')